# Why data points on Weibull plot lies outside of probability line?

Tags: data-visualization, maximum-likelihood, weibull-distribution

As shown on the pic from ReliaSoft wiki site below. Data points located not exactly on the probability line. If parameters estimated with MLE, then F(t) for plotting data points and probability line shall be the same, right ?
do they additionally estimated F(t) of data points using regression method? if so, what benefits it gives to?

[image]

Comment: I am starting to think that this is related to another recent posting -- https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/496450/52554. Are you both working on the same homework assignment?

Comment: @RussLenth No its not related,  i am asking the following: suppose i get parameters of weibull distribution with fitting data by MLE and now i want to plot it. isn't F(t) of failure data shall be plotted exactly on the same points where the probability line ? and why some plots ( as shown in the pic) for data estimated with MLE  shows data not on the probability line